# how to implement ios & android google login in capacitor?

Tags: firebase, google-authentication, capacitor, quasar

I am using capacitor-firebase-auth to set up my app. Already follow below guide line to setup, but the result still return

"CapacitorFirebaseAuth" plugin is not implemented on ios
URL: undefined

is anyone know what is problem?

Add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project:
Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.
Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the URL that is requested in the info.plist file of your project, you will find this in the main target of your app   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLLgf.png

Btw, you will probably also need to add GoogleService-Info.plist to your project as well if you haven't already, you can find this in the project settings of your firebase panel (cog icon top left on firebase dashboard) and setup the SDK for iOS etc.

If you don't know your reversed-client ID, follow the instructions above to get the GoogleService-Info.plist, it is located in that file. Firebase will also give you instructions as to how to configure your project.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have add plist file to my ios project and i also copy the reverseed client id to url schemes. i did both of things but in my ios simulator, it still return "CapacitorFirebaseAuth" plugin is not implemented on ios URL: undefined.

Therefore, i am thinking am i missing any steps.

It works on website.But not working on android & ios

Comment: Did you run a pod install from the app directory of the app itself after adding CapacitorFirebaseAuth? I need more detailed error logs to be able to help you if you can post that during runtime. Ensure you have also run the 'npx cap sync' command and ensure you have correctly configured your capacitor config json or ts file with Capacitor Firebase Auth

Comment: thanks, the problem solve when running pod install, the package not found in the podfile, as i am using quasar to wrap capacitor, it needs in install package inside capacitor. 

For now it works on ios, but fail in android, already add the sha1 follow the instruction: 
https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

Comment: it only show capacitor plugin is not implemented on android

Comment: Capacitor for Android doesn't use the `google-info.plist` file, there is a separate SDK that you can setup (you can find it in the same place in your project settings of firebase, add that new file (I believe it's `google-services.json` (don't quote me on name), add that to your android app, and re-test)